# Laravel how to optimize an expensive calculation in memory?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wrote a function for an average calculation for a school class.
The logic is:
As input, I have a number of students, a number of subjects, a number of notes in each subject.
Each student has an average in each subject.
In each subject, the two-note student and the average of the two grades average the subject. In the absence of a note, the system sets a zero.
There is a period to collect the notes and at the end of the collection, the system calculates the averages automatically.

```
//firt step, fill zero if note is missed
foreach ($students  as $student){
  foreach ($subjects as $subject){
    $this->checkNotes($student,$subject);
   }
 }

//step two, calcul avarage
foreach ($students->chunk(100) as $chunk){
  foreach ($chunk as $student){
    foreach ($subjects as $subject){
       $this->subjectAverage($student, $subject)
      }
   }
}
```

The function works with small volume of data. Example if I have 10 students, 5 subjects, 2 notes for each subject ... But when I have a big data request, eg: 50000 students, 30 subjects, 2 notes for each subject ... the application crashes the whole system. I tried to implement the function as chunk () on the candidate collection but I still have the same results. How to optimize such a calculation? thanks for the help

Comment: What does `checkNotes()` and `subjectAverage()` do? You might have an issue with n+1 queries, which eagerloading in Eloquent is a good solution for. If you set up your models/relationships, you can call `Student::with(["notes", "subjects"])` etc, and any looping will be much faster (since you don't have to reach out to the DB)

Comment: You could store an average for a student in your database. Disadvantage: Every time a new note is added you need to update the average, but in OOP this should be easy. Advantage: You don't have to do all those calculations in one time.

Comment: @TimLewis checkNotes () scans for each student in each subject to check for missing notes. If there is a missing note, the system is replaced by zero.
subjectAverage () calculates the average for each student in each subject

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank a lot! It is a way to exploit. But for now I have to generate the averages with the available notes.

Comment: You don't *have* to do that as two steps - add the check and replace with 0 as part of the `subjectAverage()` call.  That would allow you to follow the advice of @TimLewis and load your entire dataset as a batch and just process it through a single loop. But either way, it'll be tough to give super specific help without seeing the code behind your methods here, because that's where any resource consuming code would lay.

Comment: @Jason Thanks, finally I turned to the stored procedures under mariadb which seems to be the solution for me. Thank you all